# How to execute R functions within HTML file

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to call R functions within a HTML file which will accept a filename selected by the user and plot a graph. The R function are as follows:

```
plotGraph<-function(filename){

    test.ecg <- read.table(filename, quote="\"", comment.char="")
    ecg=ts(test.ecg)
    plot(ecg)

}
```

I have looked at opencpu, deployr and shiny.But, I am looking for a way to embed the R function in the same HTML page and pass the filename that the user selected from into the R function within the same HTML?Can it be done?

Comment: please search for r2html package

Comment: while searching for r2html package, I came across knitr package. Is it possible to do this as well in knitr?

Comment: ah i dont know ,dont have any experience with that

Comment: It's ok. Thanks. Do you have any examples of r2html code?